# Playframework, convert map to json

Tags: json, playframework

I have a map (this is in a scala template file)

```
<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>>
```

How do i convert this to a json string?

I've tried

```
@Json.stringify(Json.toJson(moduleId2DecileMap))
```

This does not work, it complains that it doesn't know what to do with a Map (sigh).

GSON isn't available, as whenever I import GSON playframework bursts, so I need a solution using the in-built play json thing or some other json framework.

OH i was using the wrong import- i had

```
@import play.api.libs.json._
```

YOU NEED

```
@import play.libs.Json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH i was using the wrong import- i had

```
@import play.api.libs.json._
```

YOU NEED

```
@import play.libs.Json
```